# "Resource" error in my old project after a new installation of Android Studio (Google Maps)

Tags: android, android-studio, maps, google-play-services

after I installed Android Studio on my new PC and imported my old and working project, I can't run the app on my smartphone. Before I could run the app I had some errors in a ...v21.xml file, which I could fix with updating my build gradle. I updated the parameters from "19.+" to the new version "22.0.0".
build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

I installed all SDKs, Google Play Services, created a new Key for Google Maps and implemented it, installed the newest USB drivers and so on, but I can`t run the app on my Nexus 6 (Android 5.1). The app is always crashing before an activity is showing.
I always get this error in the log:

```
08-28 13:25:30.265  28056-28056/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-28 13:25:30.310  28056-28056/de.touristenfahrerforum.MarcelMoiser W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
```

Followed by this log:

```
08-28 13:25:30.371  28056-28056/de.touristenfahrerforum.MarcelMoiser D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-28 13:25:30.372  28056-28056/de.touristenfahrerforum.MarcelMoiser E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.touristenfahrerforum.MarcelMoiser, PID: 28056
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.touristenfahrerforum.MarcelMoiser/de.touristenfahrerforum.MarcelMoiser.Activities.MainMenuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at de.touristenfahrerforum.MarcelMoiser.Activities.MainMenuActivity.onCreate(MainMenuActivity.java:97)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-28 13:30:30.440  28056-28056/de.touristenfahrerforum.MarcelMoiser I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 28056 SIG: 9
```

Edit:
The error seems to be in the MainMenuActivity, although it worked like this before. It's an activity with a drawer menu:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity
{
    private String[] menuItems;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    private CharSequence drawerTitle;
    private CharSequence title;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

        //Standartwerte für die Einstellungen erzeugen
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

        title = drawerTitle = getTitle();
        menuItems      = new String[]{getString(R.string.startmenu), getString(R.string.load_table_button), getString(R.string.settings)};
        drawerLayout   = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_menu);
        drawerList     = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        //Setzt den Schatten über das Menü
        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        //Holt sich den Wert für die Umrechnung zwischen PX und DP
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        V.LOGICAL_DENSITY = metrics.density;

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, menuItems));
        // Set the list's click listener
        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(title);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(drawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); <----------- Error here, Nullpointer
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }
```

And here is the XML part from the manifest file:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainMenuActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: are you using support Activity? .... then why are you using getActionBar()? ... use proper method for getting action bar with support library

Comment: @Hömafreak : Are you sure that your activity is not full screen activity ..??

Comment: @Hömafreak : This ''java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference'' happens when action bar is not displaying in activity..!!

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I was looking at the wrong spot for the error. It`s strange that it worked like this before.

Comment: are you using AppCompactActivity ? if yes please use getSupportActionBar()

Comment: MainMenuActivity is a normal Activity with a drawer menu

Comment: It's not a fullscreen activity, the error accurs when i try to get the action bar. I'll update the question with my code

Comment: Extend your activity from AppCompatActivity

Comment: Thanks everyone. Using AppCompatActicity and getSupportActionBar instead of the old code solved the problem.